# Generators of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$? I thought it should be $(1,1)$, but going through the solution of a certain exercise I am working on, it seems I am wrong.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: If you generate by $(1,1)$ you can only get to values of the form $(n,n)$, which is obviously not the whole group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just think about the group that is generated by $(1,1)$. Okay, so you certainly have $(1,1)$. You must also have the identity $(0,0)$. Also you have $2\cdot (1,1) = (2,2)$, and $3\cdot (1,1) = (3,3)$,...see the pattern?

The group generated by $(1,1)$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of elements of the form $(n,n)$. This is clearly not the entirety of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Now what about the group generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$? Every element generated by this group has the form $a\cdot (1,0) + b\cdot (0,1) = (a,b)$, which clearly is all of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Any $(m,n)$ of $\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}$ can be written $$(m,n) = (m,0) + (0,n) = \underbrace{(1,0)+\ldots+(1,0)}_{\textrm{$m$ times}} + \underbrace{(0,1)+\ldots+(0,1)}_{\textrm{$n$ times}},$$ showing that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ generate the group $\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}$. Summing $k$ times $(1,1)$ will give $(k,k)$, and you'll never be able to get elements of the form $(m,n)$ with $m\not=n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!