# How can $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ be generated by $(1,1)$ and $(0, 1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

I read somewhere that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ be generated by $(1,1)$ and $(0, 1)$ (taken together, I presume). I am trying to understand how this is true. I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160467/generators-of-mathbbz-times-mathbbz), based on which I developed the following argument:

The subgroup generated by $(1,1)$ is of the form $\{(m, n)\}$ where $m= n$. The subgroup generated by $(0, 1)$ is of the form $\{(0, n)\}$. But $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ also has elements of the form $\{(m, 0)\}$. How are they being generated by $(1,1)$ and $(0, 1)$?

Comment: Isn't it enough to note that $(1,0) = (1,1) - (0,1)$?

Comment: Consider the determinant of the square matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following: $(m,n)=m(1,1)+(n-m)(0,1)$. This shows that $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z} \subseteq \langle (1,1), (0,1)\rangle$. The other inclusion is obvious.

To answer your second question:  If you want $(m,0)$, then we can have $$(m,0)=m(1,1)+(-m)(0,1).$$

Comment: Let me just add that: $(m,n)=m(1,1)+(n−m)(0,1)$ and this is the only way for any element $(m, n)$ in $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ with generators (1, 1) and (0, 1).

Comment: Would it be correct to write: since $(m, n) = \underbrace{(1, 1) + \dots + (1, 1)}_{m \textrm{ times}} + \underbrace{(0, 1) + \dots + (0, 1)}_{(n - m) \textrm{ times }}$, we have that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ can be generated by $(0, 1), (1, 1)$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson If I understand your notation correctly, then I would say NO because $n-m$ can be a negative integer. For example, $(7,5)=\color{red}{7}(1,1)+\color{blue}{(-2)}(0,1)$. So saying I am adding $(0,1)$ minus $2$ times is not sound. If you think in terms of vectors (see Ethan Bolker's answer) and interpret the scalar multiplication by $-2$ as reversing the direction, then yes we can interpret it that way. Same issue with say $(-7,0)$.

Comment: @AnuragA Are there any non-geometrical ways of interpreting the $(n-m)(0, 1)$ term in your answer, other than the one I attempted in my previous comment?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson for $a<0$, you can think of $a(1,0)=|a|[-(1,0)]=$ adding the **additive inverse** of $(1,0)$ $|a|$ many times.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{alignat}{1}
\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} &= \{(m,n)\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\} \\
&= \{m(1,1)+(n-m)(0,1)\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\} \\
&= \{m(1,1)+l(0,1)\mid m,l\in\mathbb{Z}\} \\
&= \langle (1,1),(0,1)\rangle
\end{alignat}

Note that the last but one equality holds because, for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, the map $f_n\colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, $m\mapsto n-m$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

One way to view $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is by way of the [presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group)

$$\langle a, b\mid ab=ba\rangle.\tag{1}$$

Think of $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(0,1)$.

Introduce a new generator and relation (by way of [Tietze transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations)) in $(1)$ as follows:

$$\langle a, b, c\mid ab=ba, c=ab\rangle,\tag{2i}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\langle a, b, c\mid c=ba, cb^{-1}=a\rangle,\tag{2ii}$$

*i.e.*,

$$\langle b, c\mid c=bcb^{-1}\rangle.\tag{2iii}$$

This gives $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ as the group given by

$$\langle b, c\mid cb=bc\rangle.\tag{3}$$

Now think of $c=ab$ as $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you think geometrically you may see why with integer combinations of the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$ you can reach any vector with integer coordinates. In particular,
$$
(0,1) =  (1,1) - (1,0).
$$

(This is essentially @AnuragA 's correct answer, in another light.)